How to reference two guide commands when plotting in R?
I'm trying to plot some melted data to make a map and I want to use both the "guide_colorsteps" and "guide_colorbar" functions in scale_fill_binned(), but R doesn't seem to like it. I'm trying to figure out how to use both (it's hopefully trivial to figure out)
ggplot(rwc_poll_melt, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + scale_fill_binned(low = "white", high = "red",name=paste('Emissions (tons/yr)'), guide = guide_colorsteps(show.limits = TRUE), guide = guide_colorbar(frame.colour="black", ticks.colour="black"))
formal argument "guide" matched by multiple actual arguments
I've tried a few syntax changes, but can't figure it out

I don't think you can have two types of guides for the same scale. You certainly can't define it that way. You could potentially fake things with a color and fill scale, but I wonder what it is that you are actually trying to achieve, do you really want two very similar looking guides? Can you give a reproducible example (see e.g. the examples in ?scale_fill_binned) and an explanation or drawing of what the plot should look like?

One potential option is to use the ggnewscale package to add another 'fill' scale, e.g.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggnewscale)

# Minimal reproducible example
x <- LETTERS[1:20]
y <- paste0("var", seq(1,20))
data <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
data$value <- runif(400, 0, 5)

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_binned(low = "white", high = "red", name=paste('Emissions (tons/yr; binned)'),
                    guide = guide_colorsteps(show.limits = TRUE)) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_tile(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "white", high = "red", name=paste('Emissions (tons/yr; continuous)'),
                        guide = guide_colorbar(frame.colour="black", ticks.colour="black"))


Created on 2024-09-18 with reprex v2.1.0
Is that what you want to achieve? Or have I misunderstood?
